# Three.js changing mesh texture changes whole model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a model with a lot of meshes. I want to apply texture only to a single mesh. But the problem is that the whole model changes it's texture. What am I'm doing wrong ?

```
function load_models(callback) {
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    loader.load(baseDir + 'files/' + model.model_name, function (object) {
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                var mesh = model.meshes.filter(function(mesh) {
                    return mesh.name == child.name;
                }).shift();

                if (mesh.is_fiberboard == true) {
                    child.material.map = mesh.material.texture;
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                    child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                    child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
                }
            }
        });
        callback();
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a issue in Three.js 76. It was gone after updating to Three.js 79.